# ionic 2 doesn't detects mobile browser

Tags: android, cordova, ionic2

In my ionic 2 app running on a web server and as an android app, I want to detect if the client is

1. A desktop browser
2. Mobile browser
3. Or if it is the app.

With the following code I will only get 'core' for desktop browser and for the android app and the mobile browser (chrome on android, std. browser setup) I will get the same values. (cordova, android, mobile)

I am using following code:

```
constructor(public plt: Platform) {
   var platforms = this.plt.platforms(); 
}
```

As in the [API Documents](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/platform/Platform/) described, I am expecting to get also the value **'mobileweb'**.

Answer (score 0):

> Depending on what device you are on, platforms can return multiple values

These "multiple" values vary depending on the device and are not all the platform names that are avalible. It might be more useful to create a conditional based on the `mobileweb` platform name

```
if (this.plt.is('mobileweb')) {
   // Do mobileweb specific stuff here
}
```

This approach i think more reliable way to specify functionality based on platform type.

Comment: But I dont get 'mobileweb' back on my android device in the chrome browser.